# Validating user's API credentials - PayPal DoDirectPayment

Tags: api, paypal, credentials

Hello I am working on a site that accept PayPal API Credentials for every restaurant owner so that amount could be transferred to their account directly.

The problem that I am facing, some times restaurant owners add wrong API credentials so when any order is placed the error "Security Header is not valid" appears means their API credentials is wrong.

The solution I want is that the API Credentials could be verified when they are added by restaurant owner, so that order could be placed by end user.

Is there any way to Verify/Validate PayPal API Credentials(User Name, Password, Signature), Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Programming Language Are You?

Comment: We are using PHP language for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal Don't have any External API to validate the API Credentials alone.
instead. You can Use the Express Checkout SETEXPRESSCHEKOUT API to call with very Minimal data and the API credentials, which will validate the API credentials and will generate a Token. If you get a Token it means the API credentials is correct. This will not do any money Movement with this API Call. PP have this API available in both NVP and SOAP format.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the same way with GetBalance API, If the API credentials is correct then we get the following response 
Array
(
    [ACK] => Success
)
OR If the API credentials is not correct then we get the following response
Array
(
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
On the basis of this response we can get the Status Of the PayPal API credentials. I thin this option will be right, what say? I tested with Sandbox AND Live PayPal API Credentials.

Comment: Is this the correct way that I am going to use? As I tested with SETEXPRESSCHEKOUT API calls as suggested by you but I didn't get the suitable response, I am always getting transaction refused due to some missing parameters.